# Preventing Android ADT from including duplicate JAR files

Tags: android, jar, version

When Eclipse launches and compiles my project, it will include duplicate JAR files and generate a dx error that indicates that classes already exist. Google has documented this under:

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

> Jar file are identified strictly by their file names.
>
> This means mylib.jar is different than mylib-v2.jar and both will be
>   packaged, possibly resulting in “already added” dx error if they are
>   actually the same library in a different revision.

In my case, there are two GSON files (gson-2.1 and gson-2.2.1). Only when I delete the gson-2.1 file will the project compile. Until Google adds better version detection, is there a way of preventing ADT from adding the older jar file when Eclipse launches?